# Sorting np.array x with evaluating function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have this 2D numpy array which looks like this:

```
[[ 7.13617384e+00  3.93455820e+00  8.34862014e+00  1.42756162e+03]
 [ 2.93579791e+00  4.83915611e+00 -3.41362211e-01  1.71145016e+03]
...
 [ 9.58016886e+00  2.96627154e+00 -1.43432831e+00  2.44785312e+03]
 [-1.32142476e+00  9.51850265e+00  1.77833164e+01  1.66931544e+03]]
```

There is an evaluate function that takes the 4 values per array and gives it a value, the lower the better. Now I want to sort the original array based on the lowest values that the evaluation function generates. The code looks something like this:

```
x = np.random.uniform(low=bounds_min, high=bounds_max, size=(pop_size, 4))
f = ea.evaluate(x)
sorted_f = np.sort(f)

np.argsort(x, order(sorted_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use argsort to get the order of the values in `f` and then use these indexes to sort your original array `x`

```
x = np.random.uniform(low=bounds_min, high=bounds_max, size=(pop_size, 4))
f = ea.evaluate(x)

idx = np.argsort(f)
f = f[idx] # assuming f is an array
x = x[idx]
```